# How to find all "orphaned" user stories in Rally tool

Tags: rally

I want to find all `"orphaned"` user stories in `Rally`, where a `user story` does not belong to any `feature`. I know I need to set filter to((PortfolioItem = null) AND (Parent = null)) but where do I do that? Where do I start?
Forgive my ignorance, I am new to Rally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of options:  the Work Views page or a custom list app are both decent places to start.  Both of those apps have filters where you should be able to select a filter for Parent = -- No Entry --

Answer (score 0):

To select the orphaned user stories, the below steps while tracking every iteration status would help,

1. Add Filter on field 'Feature'
2. In the filter for 'Feature', choose the value '-- No Entry --'

This would give you the list of user stories which are not linked to a parent feature in the respective iteration